# Why do I always receive errors when using PyInstaller or and Python Installers (even for simple projects)?

Tags: python, installation, pyqt5, pyinstaller, python-3.9

I keep getting errors when I use python installers (my primary installer contains various libraries such as QSci and other libraries that are part of PyQt5). For example, when I try to convert a simple project with the code below to an executable, it errors out saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtPrintSupport'`. The projects do compile and run well though. I wonder what is wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
import sys
import os
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qsci
from PyQt5 import QtPrintSupport

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
editor = Qsci.QsciScintilla()
lexer = Qsci.QsciLexerPython(editor)
editor.setLexer(lexer)

## setup autocompletion
api = Qsci.QsciAPIs(lexer)

# import the desired api file
pyqt_path = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)
api.load(os.path.join(pyqt_path, "Qt/qsci/api/python/Python-3.6.api"))

api.prepare()
editor.setAutoCompletionThreshold(1)
editor.setAutoCompletionSource(Qsci.QsciScintilla.AcsAll)

editor.show()
editor.setText(open(sys.argv[0]).read())
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's possible that QScintilla dynamically loads the print module, and pyinstaller is not able to recognize it (module requirements are "guessed" by parsing files, and if modules are not explicitly loaded they're not automatically included). Try including the QtPrintSupport module in the pyinstaller command/script.

Comment: Ok I will check right now

Comment: Now I am getting this error ```File "codecs.py", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte```

Comment: Sorry but that error is not enough. Please [edit] your question clarifying what you tried to do.